# I am importing the data using load data local infile . I want to have one column with dynamic values in it for each rows . How can I do that?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store the value of array variable count into one of the table column . I want to iterate array variable for each inserted records .

Can I implement this ?
This is my mysql query :

```
     $count=array(1,2,3);
     $query = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "data.csv" IGNORE
               INTO TABLE data_table
               FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
               LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"
               IGNORE 1 LINES
               (@column1,@column2,@column3,@column4)
               SET name1 = @column1, name2 = @column2,  addr1 = @column3, 
               addr2 = @column4
               count=$count';
         $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
         $statement->execute();
```

Comment: Either produce a new file that includes the calculated data, or read the CSV into PHP and issue the inserts with the calculated data, or do the `LOAD INFILE` and then a second pass to add the calculated data.

Comment: what do you mean by do the LOAD INFILE and then a second pass to add the calculated data. Can this be done is a single load infile operation ?

Comment: 1. Load the data from the file as-is and then go back over the table with PHP to add the calculated values. 2. No. `LOAD DATA INFILE` will only `LOAD` `DATA` that is `IN` the `FILE`.